# Can you invite or join people to a group using the Facebook API? With events?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Can you invite or join people to a group using the Facebook API? What about with events?

I have an 'App' (Using C# Graph Facebook API) that users can accept with their account. I can create an event, post on walls, but I can't figure out how to invite people to a specific group or event. Users that accept the app should be automatically joined to the group. If that is not possible, then have the app invite them to the group. Is the later possible?

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invite a user to an event by issuing a POST to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID
```

If you want to invite multiple users, you can issue a POST like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3
```

You need the

```
create_event
```

permission

Please see the [Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) API docs.

You can't invite to a Group using the API. See [Group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) API docs.

Comment: so you can't invite to groups? can you invite to pages?

Comment: You can ask users to visit the page and like it, but not to 'join' the page. The page object doesn't have a members/attendees field. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/.

Comment: But according this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group).It says that

Applications can invite users to a group by issuing a POST request to /GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID with an app access_token.
Note that user being invited must be a user of the application. The user will be sent a notification saying that they have been invited to the group. The notification will take them to the group page.

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson : sir can you please reply here ?? Thanks.